# Expire build in TestFlight when it is the Appstore version

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I have an app for which version 1.5, build 26 is already live and doing well enough on the app store. Now I uploaded a new version (1.6, build 54) to TestFlight, but it's not becoming available to anyone.

It turns out my 1.5, build 26 is also still listed on TestFlight. Obviously, there is no longer any need for that. Can I expire that build (and hopefully have my new version become available), or will that also remove it from the app store?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expiring the TestFlight build will have no impact on the released build. But also this will not make your new build available. To make the new build available you will need to submit it for TestFlight beta review and have it approved. Once approved you can make it available to testers.